# How to get current duration of seekbar when click on seekbar

Tags: android, media-player, seekbar

I have a question is How to get current duration of seekbar when click on seekbar?
Thanks!

I've already try this code but it's not work:

```
seekBar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("debug", String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

At any time, you can call SeekBar.getProgress() to get the current value.  To do this when the seekbar is clicked, set an OnClickListener (SeekBar.setOnClickListener) and to do this when the value is updated, set an OnSeekbarChangeListener

Comment: seekBar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("debug", String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
   }
  });   but it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really "click" on a seekBar per se - try `seekBar.setOnSeekbarChangeListener`

Comment: that method have 3 method override so what is the method will work when I click on seekbar?

Comment: Not good, if I override that method by add this line: Log.i("debug", String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));  ==> it will print the current duration all the time when seekbar work, not clicked :(

Comment: you don't need to seekbar.getProgress. you can use the progress variable supplied by the method. public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)

Comment: But when seekbar work, the onProgressChanged will work too. I need when I click on seekbar then get the current duration :(

Comment: then try doing it in onStopTracking. seriously, everything is in front of you.